# How to get gradient in treemap using echarts

Tags: gradient, treemap, echarts

I have a single hierarchy and based on values, I want gradient based on values on my map. I have used echarts for this. The solution given in their examples is hard to implement for getting a gradient. I have used React JS to achieve this. Here's my code along with json here -

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
// import the core library.
import ReactEchartsCore from 'echarts-for-react/lib/core';
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";
// then import echarts modules those you have used manually.
import echarts from 'echarts/lib/echarts';
import 'echarts/lib/chart/treemap';
import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip';
import 'echarts/lib/component/title';

var treemapData = [
    {
        "name": "abcdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "value": 250,

    },
    {
        "name": "xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzzz",
        "value": 525,

    },
    {
        "name": "mnopmnopmnop",
        "value": 1120,

    },
    {
        "name": "vsuuuuuuuuuvu",
        "value": 216,

    },
    {
        "name": "1232342343434",
        "value": 400,

    },
    {
        "name": "timetimetime",
        "value": 297,

    },
    {
        "name": "placeplaceplace",
        "value": 208,

    },
    {
        "name": "countrycountry",
        "value": 1203,

    }
];

function TreemapEcharts() {

    return (
        <ReactEcharts

            option={{

                series: [{
                    type: 'treemap',
                    data: treemapData,
                    label: {
                        normal: {
                            textStyle: {
                                ellipsis: true
                            },
                            position: 'insideCenter',
                            formatter: function (params) {
                                var arr = [
                                    '{name|' + params.name + '}',
                                    '{value|' + params.value + '}'
                                ];
                                return arr.join('\n');
                            },
                            rich: {
                                name: {
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: '#fff'
                                },
                                value: {
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    color: '#fff'
                                },
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    levels: [
                        {
                            itemStyle: {
                                normal: {
                                    borderWidth: 2,
                                    borderColor: '#fff',
                                    gapWidth: 2
                                  }
                            }
                            
                        },
                       
                    ],

                }]
            }}

            style={{ height: '300px', width: '50%' }}
        />
    )
}
export default TreemapEcharts
```

Please let me know how can we add a gradient where color varies from darkest shade to lightest shade of one color here.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still wondering, you should take a look at their document regarding `level`: https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-treemap.levels.

Basically, you need to configure a color range and set `colorMappingBy` to "value". You should have something like this for your `level` config:

```
{
    color: ["#942e38", "#aaa", "#269f3c"],
    colorMappingBy: "value",
    itemStyle: { ... }
}
```

To fine-tune your visualization, you can convert your value to an array, with the second element in the array being a value scaled to the desired saturation and map your color to that value by setting `visualDimension` to `1` (index value of the element the array), and manually set `visualMin` and `visualMax` values.

You can also take a look at their example: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=treemap-visual.